# Unity dynamic mapping

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm new to Unity Dependency Injection and have a question thats probably very straight forward..

I would like to register type mappings based on configuration pulled from my database model. How and what's the best way to do this?

For example would I do something like this?

```
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyType, /*My dynamic config value*/>();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify target types in your database using [assembly qualified names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx)

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
//container.RegisterType<IFoo,Foo>();
Type to = Type.GetType("TestApp.Foo, TestApp");
container.RegisterType(typeof(IFoo),to);
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
Assert.IsInstanceOf<Foo>(foo);
```